# Simple python2.7 code not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was creating a little guessing game in python 2.7 to help expand my programming skills and there is a bug in it that I don't know how to fix.  The problem is that no matter what I guess, it will always print "You guessed too high. :("  I have tried everything that I know to fix it, but nothing is working.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what might fix this?   My code is as follows:

```
import random

guess_one = raw_input("Guess a number from one to ten")
answer = random.randrange(1,10)

if guess_one < answer:
    print "You guessed too low. :("
elif guess_one > answer:
    print "You guessed too high. :("
else:
    print "Congrats! You guessed correctly! :D"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user input comes in as a string, which will always be higher than an integer, so the entry will always be too high.

You need to convert the input to int to have this work:

```
guess_one = int(raw_input("Guess a number from one to ten"))
```

That should do it.

Also note that `randrange(x,y)` returns a value from x-y that includes x but excludes y. So what you want in your code (for 1-10) is `randrange(1,11)`